# How to Use AssetsLibrary.framework for open a Custom camera in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, assetslibrary

I want to Open a custom camera.

[image]

I try that but not do this type of open custom camera like above image , this isn't really exactly what I wanted. I am new to AssetsLibrary.framework. How to open custom camera like above image?

Comment: Use assets library and customize the camera overlay and add it as overlay view. if you need a sample project you can get from here. http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g00f340c6b38456e399925755560d8b60b9870b7f4

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CameraOverlay for this.And try to use the method
[Camera takePicture] to click the pick.
Check for camera customization using Overaly view, you will find the answer.

Cheers..